# DataTable, Facing issue with select filter when using mRender

Tags: javascript, datatable, datatables

I need to filter specific text only but it short only exact value.

[image]

> I want to show row if a value in filter select is match.

Comment: Your question is not very clear to what exactly you are trying to achieve. Also a jsFiddle would be helpful...

Comment: in datatables, there is a search box

Comment: @juntapao
here is a demo 
http://jsfiddle.net/tarifrudrapur/kg2gyp5e/8/

Comment: @MaVRoSCy Find my demo in comments. If user hi a option there should be all related list display in table

Comment: @Tarif Khan, yes but why don't you want to use the built-in search box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using the search functionality of datatables.

However if you insist, change the regex pattern, instead of

```
column.search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false ).draw();
```

replace it with (removing `^` and `$` to search anywhere in the string)

```
column.search( val ? val : '', true, false ).draw();
```

See sample below:

http://jsfiddle.net/kg2gyp5e/10/